# Laravel: querying for all records with a timestamp from today

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an Orders table that has a field `scan_date` in unix timecode.  I am trying to get all Orders with a `scan_date` WITHIN the current day.  I was originally using `whereBetween()` to grab orders within the last 24 hours of whenever it's run but I realized that's not doing exactly what I need.

```
->whereBetween('scan_date', [Carbon::now()->addDays(-1), Carbon::now()])
```

If an order has a `scan_date` between 12:01AM and 11:59pm on the current day, I want to grab all those orders -- is this possible to query for?

Comment: Why not just `whereDate('scan_date', Carbon::today())`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  I should mention I am on Laravel 5.4.  Isn't the above only for Laravel 5.6+?  I tried that and the query is failing with a `500`.  I also tried `whereDate('scan_date', '=', Carbon::today())` and still failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to what you were doing, with a small modification:

```
$today = \Carbon\Carbon::today();
$startOfDayTimestamp = $today->copy()->startOfDay()->timestamp;
$endOfDayTimestamp = $today->copy()->endOfDay()->timestamp;

->whereBetween('scan_date', [
    $startOfDayTimestamp,
    $endOfDayTimestamp
])
```

Comment: @burtonLowel I was testing and I made a modification because both dates were giving me the end of the day, note the `->copy()` to not modify the same object.

Comment: And i removed the accesor option, because can use accessor only when already have object instance, and  won't be able to use it when querying database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereDate`, on Laravel < 5.7 you should format the date to `Y-m-d` before passing it:

```php
->whereDate('scan_date', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
```

On Laravel >= 5.7 you can pass an instance of `DateTimeInterface` directly:

```php
->whereDate('scan_date', Carbon::now())
```